# Merge (or concat 、combine ?) a Object 's array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

hello I'm a Js newbie and use stackoverflow to ask first question.

when I use Jquery's Ajax() to get a JSON response .

It look like:

1.response_data from php with //JSON_encode(response_data);

2.data_array = JSON.parse (response_data) // after parse it look like:

```
data_array = [[student : John , Score :{10, 40, 22}],
              [student : Mary , Score :{20, 50, 66}],
              [student : Ken  , Score :{30, 60, 88}]];
```

3.How would I go about making this just

```
a = [10,20,30];
b = [40,50,60];
c = [22,66,88];
```

4.Because i need to give every one's score to different object

```
Math : [10, 20, 30];
English : [40, 50, 60];
physics : [22, 66, 88];
```

Comment: Isnt data_array supposed to be [{ student: John, Score:[10,20,30]},...]. I mean an array of objects and Score being an array of numbers?

Comment: your "json" is messed up

Comment: i put data in php page like : $response_data[0][0] : array("student":name, "score" : point)

Comment: // $response_data[0][$i]   is first student's data , $response_data[1][$i] is second student;s data

Comment: I think i have a little confuse in javascript 's  「Object」 and 「array」 when they Combination a JSON .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forEach method of the Array Object on data_array. Read more about foreach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var data_array = [{student : "John" , Score :[10, 40, 22]},
              {student : "Mary" , Score :[20, 50, 66]},
              {student : "Ken"  , Score :[30, 60, 88]}];
console.log(data_array);

var math_arr = [];
var english_arr=[];
var physics_arr = [];

data_array.forEach(function(i){
   math_arr.push(i.Score[0])
   english_arr.push(i.Score[1])
   physics_arr.push(i.Score[2])

});
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "Math Score " + math_arr + "<br/>"+ "English Score " + english_arr + "<br/>"+"Physics Score " + physics_arr + "<br/>";

console.log(math_arr,english_arr,physics_arr);
```

```html
<div id="app">
   
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The data_array variable I think is mistyped but to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
var new_array = data_array.map(function(item){
    return item.Score;
});

var a = new_array[0], b = new_array[1], c = new_array[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to write a function to do that:

```
function getScore(data_array) {
    var scores = { a: [], b: [], c: [] };

    for (var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++) {
        scores.a.push(data_array[i].Score[0]);
        scores.b.push(data_array[i].Score[1]);
        scores.c.push(data_array[i].Score[2]);
    }
    return scores;
}
```

So when you call `getScore(data_array)`, you will get the result as:

```
{
    a: [10,20,30],
    b: [40,50,60],
    c: [22,66,88]
}
```

Comment: if I only need Math's Score , just write getScore(data_array).a ?

Comment: yes. or you can assign it to the variable `var score = getScore(data_array); var math = score.a;`. Which ever should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var englishScore = [];
var mathScore = [];
var physicsScore = [];

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    score = data[i].Score.split(",");
    englishScore.push(score[0]);
    mathScore.push(score[1]);
    physicsScore.push(score[2]);
}
```

Hope it helps.